# insert int date into database table in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I tried to insert integer date value into the database but it only postdates like if my date is (23-09-2019) it post 23 to the database I want to insert this date like an integer date value.

Here is my view code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker7" name="entity_expired" value="" placeholder="Date" autocomplete="off">
```

Here is my modal code:

```
$entity_expired = trim($_POST['entity_expired']);

$data = array('entity_expired' => $entity_expired);
$this->db->where('entity_id',$entity_id);
$this->db->update('tbl_entity',$data);
```

Comment: what do you mean by `date like an integer date value`? any expected output?

Comment: 1569208561 like this todays date convert into int value

Comment: What is your column datatype?

Comment: entity_expired datatype is --> int(11)

Comment: normally Date is stored in date type in db (for mysql datetime) , later you can convert inserted date to any date format with the help of php date() ref :https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: but when I change input type **text** to **date** it perfectly works

Comment: you cannot use datatype int because integer type will not save hyphen values

Comment: I have no hyphen values

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this :

```php
$entity_expired = strtotime(trim($_POST['entity_expired']));

$data = array('entity_expired' => $entity_expired);
$this->db->where('entity_id',$entity_id);
$this->db->update('tbl_entity',$data);
```

And to retrive `entity_expired` date later :

```php
$entity_expired = date('Y-m-d', $data->entity_expired);
```

Comment: not working its only post 1970 if I update any data see image: https://ibb.co/rmg2Fsj

Comment: what is the format of the `$_POST['entity_expired']`?

Comment: In database datatype is `int`

Comment: I'm not asking about your db column, i'm asking the `$_POST['entity_expired']` format being sent

Comment: I already mentioned it to my question. input type is `text` while I use datepicker